# UIBarButtonItems are randomly resizing in bottom UIToolBar

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, xcode5, uitoolbar

I added a UIToolbar on the bottom a view controller in IB.

I added a few UIBarButtonItems, but it seems to randomly resize either when I click on one of the UIBarButtons or if I leave the view and come back to it.

Is there any reason why it is doing this? I didn't have this issue when I was running iOS6, but on iOS7, xCode 5 the words shrink and expand randomly.

Is there anyway to lock the size or fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I were having same problem and solve by writing code of assign tool bar item in viewWillLoad from viewDidLoad. i hope you will have same luck.

Comment: @jageen didn't seem to have any effect unfortunately.